# Numeric overflow in expression при складывании String

Tags: java, android, android-bundle

```
bundle.putString("javaText", getString(R.string.btn2javaA1  + R.string.btn2javaA2));
```

С одним все работает, если сложить, то не хочет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы немного ошиблись. И теперь вы не складываете String. А складываете их id. Это int значение. Попробуйте

```
bundle.putString("javaText", getString(R.string.btn2javaA1)  + getString(R.string.btn2javaA2));
```

Comment: все верно, уже сам нашел эту ошибку. Спасибо)